# Duplicate specific text in text file, using perl or grep

Tags: bash, awk, grep, perl

I need to duplicate part of a plain text file as follows:

The text file consists of a sequence of "pages", of the form:

```
<page    [lots of lines of text]       /page>

<page    [lots of lines of text]       /page>

<page    [lots of lines of text]       /page>

<page    [lots of lines of text]       /page>
```

and I need an automated way to duplicate say the 3rd such "page".
Is there an easy way to do this? (and similarly with "3rd" replaced by "23rd" etc)

Ideally I would like a bash script that unzipped the file, then did this duplication in the resulting text file, then rezipped it. The aim of this is a hack to get xournal to duplicate pages.

Comment: sorry, it's unclear for me.

Comment: sorry if its not clear: I want to search the text file for the third instance of "<page" and then copy all the text from there up to "page>", and paste all that in the text file just after the third "page>"

Comment: Is an `awk` solution acceptable?

Comment: sure that would be great

Comment: @Phil168: is text between `<page ../page> is multiline string or separate lines?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what the difference is: its a plain text file with lots of text (and carriage returns) between the markers "<page" and "page>"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use a real markup parser for this, however interpreting your format description minimally as

```
<page line one
line two /page>
<page line three
line four /page>
<page line five
line six /page>
```

then if a quick'n'dirty `awk` solution<sup>1</sup> is acceptable you could do

```
awk -v pagenum=2 'BEGIN {RS="/page>"; ORS=RS} FNR==pagenum {print} 1' file
```

or, less cryptically

```
awk -v pagenum=2 'BEGIN {RS="/page>"; ORS=RS}; FNR==pagenum {print}; {print}' file
```

where the number of the page you wish to duplicate is passed from the shell via the `-v pagenum=` parameter.

---

If there is 'stuff' after the last `/page>` tag the above expressions may treat it as an incomplete record and add a spurious closing `/page>` record separator. In that case, the following modified expression may work better

```
awk -v pagenum=2 'BEGIN {RS="/page>"; ORS=""; OFS=""} FNR==pagenum {print $0,RT} {print $0,RT}' file
```

1. tested in `gawk` 3.1.8 and `mawk` 3.3

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to work great (but it looks like black magic as you don't even seem specify the starting "<page"). I will read up on awk...

Comment: In fact this seems to add an extra "/page>" right at the end of the file. Is there a simple way to delete this?

Comment: Hmm.. I think that perhaps your file has a trailing blank line, which the awk expression is treating as an incomplete record - let me see if I can find a workaround